# Dwellers not consuming resources?

Tags: fallout-shelter

So I was playing Fallout Shelter and my vault dwellers were all dying from lack of resources. I stopped playing for a few days until I got money to buy lunchboxes to fix them up. When I came back, all my production rooms were taking about 8 hours to produce resources. Rushing them fixed the issue, but now my dwellers won't consume resources at all! Can anyone tell me what the issue is and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Well there are some issues in the game regarding dying people. Due to the fact that your people are more than 24h dead, they disappeared right? Is your dweller counter correct or does it show the old dweller count?

Did you really check if there is no consummation? You can tab on the ressourcebars to see the values. Really no change or just an optical issue? :-)

Maybe try to close the game completely from the background, lock your phone, unlock it and open the game again. This will help in 90% of the cases.

If nothing works, I think you need to conduct the game developers and make an issue for that.

Answer (score 1):

All my dwellers are alive. And my resources are max and not being consumed at all. I figured out its from changing the date back or ahead. I accidently changed my date to the next days date and now when I changed it back to the original, same issue. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Moral of the story, don't mess with the in-game time by playing with the internal clock of the iPhone.

Comment: I didn't, it changed itself for some reason.. :/

Comment: Im going to be traveling from West coast to East coast soon. I wonder if this is going to screw over my game.

Comment: @James, change time zone instead of actual time, the game 'should' be ok with it cos good programmers check UTC time